# Creating a list of string from a string in a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to create a string on a list from a string

It looks like

```py
#My list
list_ = ['a, b, c, d', 'f, g, h, i', 'j, k, l, m', 'n, o, p, q']

#Output that I'm looking for
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
```

I got it from my code

```
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    pairs_dict[key] = row[1:]
    getlist = pairs_list.append(f"{key}, {', '.join(pairs_dict[key])}")
#pairs_dict is dictionary and pairs_list is empty list
```

Comment: sorry for interrupting, I'm new in programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it using `split()` like this -

```
list_ = ['a, b, c, d', 'f, g, h, i', 'j, k, l, m', 'n, o, p, q']
result = []
for r in list_:
   result.extend(r.split(', '))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use use `str.join` on the `list` and do a list comprehension or use `re.split` after the `join`ing the `list` like,

```
>>> list_
['a, b, c, d', 'f, g, h, i', 'j, k, l, m', 'n, o, p, q']
>>> [x.strip() for x in ','.join(list_).split(',')]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
```

Or

```
>>> import re
>>> list_
['a, b, c, d', 'f, g, h, i', 'j, k, l, m', 'n, o, p, q']
>>> re.split(r',\s*', ','.join(list_)) # split on ',' followed by 0 or more space
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fatest solution but it works:

```py
list_ = list(''.join(list_).replace(', ', ''))
```